# View setVisibility not working

Tags: android, listview

I am using loopj network library for http calls. I have Layout with ListView and progressbar in activity layout. When http call return success and post result on UI thread in onSuccess method I am call listener method onDataReceived which sets the ListView visibility to View.Visible and progressbar visibility to GONE.

Here snippet of adapter code.

```
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody){

    listenerObj.onDataReceived();
}
```

In activity

```
onDataReceived(){
 listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)
}
```

**Problem**

This approach doesn't work consistently. Sometime (20%) listview setting visibility doesn't work and progressbar remain on screen.

I am facing same problem with gridview too.

Is this correct approach or I am missing something?

Comment: Sorry..it was typo. I have edited it.

Comment: "Is this correct approach or I am missing something?" it is a correct approach, you have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @mmlooloo thanks for your response and approach validation. After your response I have rechecked the code and it seems I am doing some thing wrong while notifying the adapter. Thanks for putting me in right direction.

Comment: you are always welcome!